# Windows XP registry help needed

Tags: windows-xp

Can anyone tell me under which hive based registry setting PrefetchParameters is present?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Altering Prefetch Parameters](http://www.theeldergeek.com/prefetch_parameters_-_altering.htm)

- [Start] [Run] [Regedit]
- Registry Key:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
  Manager\Memory
  Management\PrefetchParameters

Comment: @astander: Beat me by 12 seconds. @OP: It's the **top link** of http://www.google.com/search?q=PrefetchParameters

Comment: thanx :).......................

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm if i am not wrong then u should follow the following step:

```
1. goto registry editor.
2. click on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
3. under that click on SYSTEM
4. under that click on CurrentControlSet001
5. under that click on Control
6. under that click on Session Manager
7. under that click on Memory Management
8. u will see PrefetchParameters
```

Comment: thanx :).......................